# Why does Python in Excel give a #CALC error when I try to create a dataframe from a Stockhistory array that uses Today()

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

"Python in Excel" gives a #CALC error when I try to create a Pandas dataframe from a STOCKHISTORY array that has been created using the TODAY() function

If I create a stock history array by entering the following in cell A1

> =STOCKHISTORY("MSFT", "6/2/24", "16/2/24",0,1)

Then, using Python in Excel, I can create a Pandas dataframe in another cell by entering

> df=xl("A1#", headers=True)

However, if I change cell A1 to

> =STOCKHISTORY("MSFT", TODAY()-10, TODAY(),0,1)

Then Python in Excel gives a #CALC error

Is this one of the unsupported scenarios or have I got the syntax wrong?

Comment: The scenario _is_ supported - just not with that volatile function: you can use the M code `=DateTime.Date( DateTime.LocalNow())` to generate the same value in PowerQuery, load it to a cell, and then reference that cell in your formula (as it's a PowerQuery 'result' you can define, in its properties, if/how often you want it to update).